# How I can listen for a keyword in a web browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, voice-recognition

How I can listen for a keyword from web browser and when it catched - do something using JavaScript like it implemented in google search app for android with their "Ok, google"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pocketsphinx.js:

https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js

See keyword spotting demo

https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js/blob/master/webapp/live_kws.html

Comment: Oh... That's cool. But how I can increase accuracy of recognizing. I saw it's library fires an event even if I tells nothing. It hear noises the same as keyword. Sorry for my language.

Comment: For more reliable recognition you can use longer keywords and also configure detection threshold [["-kws_threshold", "2"]]