# How does Google specify "Ok Google" as its "trigger" phrase?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition

Based on a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952997/how-ok-google-technology-is-implemented) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280430/how-i-can-listen-for-a-keyword-in-a-web-browser-with-javascript), the technique seems to be keyword spotting.  This question is more specific.

When the HTML5 Speech API is listening/recording, a red microphone icon appears in the tab.  On Google's search pages, the red icon never appears until you say the phrase "Ok Google".

How does Google enable keyword spotting without using the API?

Is the "Ok Google" built into Chrome or is there a way for anyone to define such a trigger phrase for their site?

Comment: Since both of those other questions were closed for being too broad...why would you assume your question fit the site guidelines? Use google to look for solutions

Comment: Those questions are more general than mine; Sphinx isn't the answer. I Googled for an hour before posting this question.

Comment: As Nikolay's response indicates, this question was not too broad.  His answer was succint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the "Ok Google" built into Chrome

Yes

> or is there a way for anyone to define such a trigger phrase for their site?

No

To understand technology you can check

https://wiki.inf.ed.ac.uk/twiki/pub/CSTR/ListenSemester2201314/chen2014small.pdf

Keyword spotter is trained on 40 thousand of "ok google" examples. It is not possible to change the phrase without retraining on similar amount of examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Nikolay.  That'll save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

They could just be constantly recording and ignoring everything until "Ok Google" is actually said. So therfore using the API.

For example (example code, needs more work and NOT tested)

```
rec = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
if (rec) {
   rec.onresult = function(e) {
      for (var i = e.resultIndex; i < e.results.length; ++i) {
         if (e.results[i].isFinal) {
            if (e.results[i][0].transcript.indexOf("Ok Google") > -1) {
               // listen for the rest
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have written about something similar where you can [control a video with speech](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2014/01/javascript/using-the-web-speech-api-to-control-a-html5-video) by saying "video" followed by a command.

Of course Google are probably doing something a lot better than this, but if you are trying to implement something yourself, this might point you on the correct path.

Comment: I found your site yesterday and thought the demo was cool!